# gRPC Python quickstart/helloworld (greeter_client.py) is hanging before printing "Greeter client received: ..."

Tags: python, go, grpc

Today I wanted to start implementing a gRPC client and server for a program I wrote in Python. I have followed the tutorial found here: https://grpc.io/docs/languages/python/quickstart/.

By follow I mean I have follow directions exactly, typing each command exactly as written. First installing all requirements (in a conda environemnt) then running the greeter_server.py and greeter_client.py. Techinically the program works, but the client program hangs for about 30-40 seconds on my system before responding with the simple greeting "Greeter client received: Hello, you!".

So I decided to try the Go version of the quick start tutorial found here: https://grpc.io/docs/languages/go/quickstart/. Again following all instructions exactly as writtten and building and starting both the go server and go client, the client program responds in less than a second with "2020/08/27 12:48:24 Greeting: Hello world".

The go version is behaving in exactly the way I would expect. Yet the Python version takes almost a minute to respond with a simple message. Does anyone have any idea what is going on?

Thanks in advance.

Edit 1) - I will supplement the original question with some testing I have just done. I apologize for the lack of in the original. So, I have been testing on different machines. On my desktop which is an Ubuntu 20 machine the issue is present. I can simply pop open a terminal, create a new conda environment (I have used Python 3.8 for these tests). I perform the Quick Start tutorial. The Python version is NOT working as expected (it takes far too long to convince me everythign is working properly). I perform the Quick Start in Go and every thing runs fine.

I tested this tutorial on my 2011 mac book air, starting a terminal, creating a new conda environment (3.8) and the Python version of gRPC Quick Start is working fine (as in there is no humanly noticable difference) compared to the Go version.

So I am wondering if there are any gRPC experts who would have a suggestion as to why this happens. I have restarted my machine and tested again, still the problem persists on my Ubuntu linux machine.

Edit 2) - I just ran a simiar test on an Ubuntu 20 cloud VM and everything works as expected (no difference between Python and Go versions). I tried a seprate random "echo" gRPC Python tutorial I found online (unrelated to the gRPC Quick Start tutorial) and the issue persists on my local. So I believe the issue can be isolated to my environment. I am lost.

Edit 3) - I ran the client code through a debugger and added break points.

```py
from __future__ import print_function
import logging

import grpc

import helloworld_pb2
import helloworld_pb2_grpc


def run():
    # NOTE(gRPC Python Team): .close() is possible on a channel and should be
    # used in circumstances in which the with statement does not fit the needs
    # of the code.
    with grpc.insecure_channel('localhost:50051') as channel: # added break
        stub = helloworld_pb2_grpc.GreeterStub(channel) # added break
        response = stub.SayHello(helloworld_pb2.HelloRequest(name='you')) # added break - HANGS ASSINING `response` OBJECT
    print("Greeter client received: " + response.message) # added break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig()
    run()
```

It is is hanging just before the print statement, within the with block. On my mac I set the same break points and the debugger instantly assigns the reponse object to memory and prints. On my Ubuntu machine the debugger hangs trying to assign the `response = stub.SayHello(helloworld_pb2.HelloRequest(name='you'))` variable. I have noticed the use of Cython which may be a clue.

If I interupt the greeter_client.py process I get the following trace:

```
  File "greeter_client.py", line 37, in <module>
    run()
  File "greeter_client.py", line 31, in run
    response = stub.SayHello(helloworld_pb2.HelloRequest(name='you'))
  File "/home/james/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 824, in __call__
    state, call, = self._blocking(request, timeout, metadata, credentials,
  File "/home/james/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 813, in _blocking
    event = call.next_event()
  File "src/python/grpcio/grpc/_cython/_cygrpc/channel.pyx.pxi", line 338, in grpc._cython.cygrpc.SegregatedCall.next_event
  File "src/python/grpcio/grpc/_cython/_cygrpc/channel.pyx.pxi", line 169, in grpc._cython.cygrpc._next_call_event
  File "src/python/grpcio/grpc/_cython/_cygrpc/channel.pyx.pxi", line 163, in grpc._cython.cygrpc._next_call_event
  File "src/python/grpcio/grpc/_cython/_cygrpc/completion_queue.pyx.pxi", line 63, in grpc._cython.cygrpc._latent_event
  File "src/python/grpcio/grpc/_cython/_cygrpc/completion_queue.pyx.pxi", line 42, in grpc._cython.cygrpc._next
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Edit 4) - One of the commenters had a good suggestion to test the python client and go server combination (gRPC allows this with zero effort, go gRPC). I performed the test and the Python client is still as slow or slower in responding. The go client - go server combination still quick. I believe this narrows it down to an issue on the Python client side. Thank you @DazWilkin. For completeness, the Go client - Python server works as expected in < 1 second.

Edit 5) - Last night I completely reinstalled a minimal version of Ubuntu 20.04. On a fresh system there is still about a 45 second delay for the simple greeter_client.py to respond. :(

Comment: have you tried running profilers on the two versions to compare how they perform in detail?

Comment: I have not tried profiling the source. At the moment I am assuming there is a reasonable explanation and something easy and obvious I am not seeing as to why this is happening.

Comment: It's a curious problem. Have you tried (locally) using the Python client with the Go server and the Go client with the Python server? An advantage of gRPC is that this will work and it may help eliminate issues.

Comment: Thank you @DazWilkin. I performed the test you suggested and the Python client - Go server. The issue is still present. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Did you resolve this? Perhaps try using virtualenv instead of conda? Perhaps try wrapping the `stub.SayHello` and `print(response.message)` in a `while True` possibly with a `time.sleep(1)` to eliminate startup time?

Answer (score 0):

This could be a common issue with all wrapper languages (Python, Ruby, PHP, C#, Node). The direct cause is that the C-Ares name resolver failed to resolve the IPv6 address of `localhost`. It can be circumvented by specifying an environment variable `GRPC_DNS_RESOLVER=native`, which changes the default name resolver.

Here is the hang section from the log provided by James:

```
D0831 13:09:27.577593604    6445 dns_resolver_ares.cc:184]   (c-ares resolver) resolver:0x55eaa9dbd8a0 AresDnsResolver::StartLocked() is called.
D0831 13:09:27.577596674    6445 grpc_ares_wrapper.cc:645]   (c-ares resolver) request:0x55eaa9d99b80 c-ares grpc_dns_lookup_ares_locked_impl name=localhost:50051, default_port=https
D0831 13:09:27.577653493    6445 grpc_ares_ev_driver.cc:158] (c-ares resolver) request:0x55eaa9d99b80 grpc_ares_ev_driver_create_locked
D0831 13:09:27.577679913    6445 grpc_ares_wrapper.cc:200]   (c-ares resolver) request:0x55eaa9d99b80 create_hostbyname_request_locked host:localhost port:33731 is_balancer:0 qtype:AAAA
D0831 13:09:27.577725082    6445 grpc_ares_wrapper.cc:200]   (c-ares resolver) request:0x55eaa9d99b80 create_hostbyname_request_locked host:localhost port:33731 is_balancer:0 qtype:A
D0831 13:09:27.577736032    6445 grpc_ares_wrapper.cc:227]   (c-ares resolver) request:0x55eaa9d99b80 on_hostbyname_done_locked qtype=A host=localhost ARES_SUCCESS
D0831 13:09:27.577740632    6445 grpc_ares_wrapper.cc:273]   (c-ares resolver) request:0x55eaa9d99b80 c-ares resolver gets a AF_INET result: 
  addr: 127.0.0.1
  port: 50051

D0831 13:09:27.577745522    6445 grpc_ares_ev_driver.cc:392] (c-ares resolver) request:0x55eaa9d99b80 new fd: c-ares fd: 10
D0831 13:09:27.577748092    6445 grpc_ares_ev_driver.cc:98]  (c-ares resolver) request:0x55eaa9d99b80 Ref ev_driver 0x55eaa9cfd900
D0831 13:09:27.577750552    6445 grpc_ares_ev_driver.cc:406] (c-ares resolver) request:0x55eaa9d99b80 notify read on: c-ares fd: 10
D0831 13:09:27.577753342    6445 grpc_ares_ev_driver.cc:463] (c-ares resolver) request:0x55eaa9d99b80 ev_driver=0x55eaa9cfd900 grpc_ares_ev_driver_start_locked. timeout in 120000 ms
D0831 13:09:27.577755682    6445 grpc_ares_ev_driver.cc:98]  (c-ares resolver) request:0x55eaa9d99b80 Ref ev_driver 0x55eaa9cfd900
D0831 13:09:27.577763612    6445 grpc_ares_ev_driver.cc:227] (c-ares resolver) request:0x55eaa9d99b80 ev_driver=0x55eaa9cfd900. next ares process poll time in 1000 ms
D0831 13:09:27.577765852    6445 grpc_ares_ev_driver.cc:98]  (c-ares resolver) request:0x55eaa9d99b80 Ref ev_driver 0x55eaa9cfd900
D0831 13:09:27.577773282    6445 dns_resolver_ares.cc:448]   (c-ares resolver) resolver:0x55eaa9dbd8a0 Started resolving. pending_request_:0x55eaa9d99b80
```

The tracking issue for this bug located in [grpc#24018](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/24018). For anyone still blocked by this issue, feel free to comment on the thread so it can get more attention.